# Invalid file identifier error when using fprintf

Tags: matlab, error-handling, identifier

This is my code.

```
fileID=fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(fileID,'Filename: %s\n',filename);
fprintf(fileID,'   Date: %s\n',Date);
```

I close the file later in the code. If I input the file name, it will write the file name in the file, along with the date.  However, later I try to write a user-chosen username into the .txt file

```
clearvars username
fprintf(2,'Any previous username will be overwritten\n');
fprintf('Input user name:');
username=input('','s');
fprintf(fileID,'Username: %s',username);
```

and I receive an error saying that I have an invalid file identifier and to use fopen to creat a vlid file identifier, I dont know what the problem is with my code. Ive tried different permissions when using fopen and Ive made sure the file that Im opening is in my directory.

```
    case '1'

        clearvars filename 
        fprintf(2,'Any previous filename has been cleared\n');
        fprintf('Input your chosen filename:');
        filename=input('','s');
        infinitypermission=true;

        while infinitypermission

            fprintf('How would you like the data in the file, if any, to be treated?\n');
            fprintf('1) Override data in file, if any\n');
            fprintf('2) Append data in file, if any, to the end\n');
            fprintf('Enter your choice:');
            permission=input('','s');
            Date=date;
            infinitypermission=true;

            switch permission

                case '1'

                    fileID=fopen(filename,'w');
                    fprintf(fileID,'Filename: %s\n',filename);
                    fprintf(fileID,'   Date: %s\n',Date);
                    infinitypermission=false;

                case '2'

                    fileID=fopen(filename,'a');
                    fprintf(fileID,'Filename: %s\n',filename);
                    fprintf(fileID,'  Date: %s\n',Date);
                    infinitypermission=false;

                otherwise

                    fprintf(2,'Error: Input must be 1 or 2\n');
            end
        end

    case '2'

        %clears any data that has been previously loaded
        clearvars Data Data2 Data_file Mean Median Mode Var Stdev Min Max Count filetrue
        fprintf(2,'Any previously loaded data has been cleared\n');
        fprintf('Enter the data you would like to load: ');
        Data_file=input('','s');
        %checks  to see if the file is in the directory
        filetrue=exist(Data_file,'file');


        if filetrue==2
            Data=importdata(Data_file);
            numeric=isnumeric(Data);
            fprintf('%s loaded\n', Data_file)

            infinity8=true;

            while infinity8

                fprintf('Would you like the analyze the data in total or analyze by column?\n');
                fprintf('1) In total\n');
                fprintf('2) By column\n');
                fprintf('Enter your choice:');
                choice4=input('','s');

                switch choice4

                    case '1'

                        Data=vertcat(Data(:,1),Data(:,2));
                        Mean=mean(Data);
                        Median=median(Data);
                        Mode=mode(Data);
                        Var=var(Data);
                        Stdev=std(Data);
                        Min=min(Data);
                        Max=max(Data);
                        Count=length(Data);
                        infinity8=false;

                    case '2'

                        Mean=mean(Data);
                        Median=median(Data);
                        Mode=mode(Data);
                        Var=var(Data);
                        Stdev=std(Data);
                        Min=min(Data);
                        Max=max(Data);
                        Count=length(Data);
                        infinity8=false;

                    otherwise
                        fprintf(2,'Error: Must enter 1 or 2\n');
                end
            end


            switch numeric %tests to see if the data is useable

                case '0'
                    fprintf(2,'Error: Data must be numeric .txt file \n');
                    clear
            end %end of switch
        else
            fprintf(2,'Error: File not found in directory\n');
        end


    case '3'
        %clears data and any variables that go with it
        clearvars Data Data2 Data_file
        fprintf(2,'Data cleared\n\n');

    case '4'

        clearvars username
        fprintf(2,'Any previous username will be overwritten\n');
        fprintf('Input user name:');
        username=input('','s');
        fprintf(fileID,'Username: %s',username);
```

Comment: Did you call `fclose(fileID)` somewhere between your `infinitypermission` and your `clearvars` call? Because you never define `fileID` again in the second chunk

Comment: I call fclose('all') at the very first line of code in case any files are open. Then I use the code above to open the file. I then use fclose('all') at the very last line of code

Comment: Can you post the code that is between these two chunks?

Comment: Its long and menu driven but this is what I have in between those two sections.

Comment: Can anyone see an issue? I still havent figured it out